# Join behavior when a table is not joined using its own key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 a
Inner Join Table2 b on a.Key = b.Key
Inner Join Table3 c on a.Key = b.Key
```

What is happening? I recently made this error in some code (wanted instead to join c on on `a.Key = c.Key`), and while I discovered and fixed it, I was surprised it was allowed to execute and get a result.

I was curious what happens when such a query is called. From what I can tell, it executes a cross join between (table1 join table2) and table3?

Comment: Since it is a *condition that is always true*, it is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM Table1 a Inner Join Table2 b on a.Key=b.Key Inner Join Table3 c on 1=1`, eg a cartesian product of (t1 join t2) * t3.

Comment: Yes, it effectively does a CROSS JOIN in that case.  It allows this because it allows any set of logical conditions in the ON clause and it assumes that this is intentional.  (which is good because there are cases and tricks that exploit this).

Comment: @wildplasser . . . You are correct.  You should place this as an answer.

Comment: And so I did. At your service!

Comment: I put the on on a separate line and line em up to help catch that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a condition that is always true, it is equivalent to:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 a 
 Inner Join Table2 b on a.Key=b.Key
 Inner Join Table3 c on 1=1
   ;
```

,eg a cartesian product of (t1 join t2) * t3.